# matrix factorization with non-negative constraint only on one of the factors

Tags: factor-analysis, svd, matrix-decomposition, spectral-analysis, non-negative-matrix-factorization

I have a 2D spectral data time series with a wavelength dimension and a time dimension, and I'd like to decompose it to the time evolution ($SV^T$ for SVD and $H$ for NNMF) of several spectral complements ($U$ for SVD and $W$ for NNMF).

The time traces must be non-negative and spectra must NOT have sign constraints.

- SVD gives negative elements in both left and right singular vectors.
- NNMF, as it should, gives non-negative elements for both factors.
- What I need is somewhere in the middle: non-sign-constraint left
  vectors and non-negative right vectors.

Is it possible to alter the algorithm of SVD or NNMF to achieve that ? Perhaps using the result of SVD or NNMF as initiation of some sort of optimization ?

I'm not very familiar with statistics, so could you please define all the terms if you use mathematical expressions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done by modifying the iterative update loop, which set a minimum value of 0 of vectors:

```
 if ismult
    % Multiplicative update formula
     numer = w0'*a;
     h = max(0,h0 .* (numer ./ ((w0'*w0)*h0 + eps(numer))));
     numer = a*h';
     w = max(0,w0 .* (numer ./ (w0*(h*h') + eps(numer))));
 else
     % Alternating least squares
     h = max(0, w0\a);
     w = max(0, a/h);
 end
```

Now relax the criteria of one of the vectors (w):

```
if ismult
    % Multiplicative update formula
    numer = w0'*a;
    h = max(0,h0 .* (numer ./ ((w0'*w0)*h0 + eps(numer))));
    numer = a*h';
    w = w0 .* (numer ./ (w0*(h*h') + eps(numer)));
else
    % Alternating least squares
    h = max(0, w0\a);
    w = a/h;
end
```